# Python autocomplete in VS Code not working with external libraries in conda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, conda, openmesh

I have installed several libraries into a conda environment named "foo". I am using Visual Studio Code as my IDE.

Autocomplete works fine for almost all packages, except for the library "openmesh" (see below):
[image: Autocomplete with openmesh]

[image: Autcomplete with a different library]

I have selected the correct python interpreter in VS Code:
[image: Interpreter]

As confirmed in the bottom left corner.

[image: Version]

Furthermore, I have tried to add it to the autocomplete path in the settings of VS Code, however, there was no change, even after relaunching.

[image: Extra Paths]

Autocomplete works fine with PyCharm, as seen here:
[image: Pycharm]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ctrl+Click on the `openmesh`, can you get into the module? `openmesh` has not been colored, it's a little weird.

Comment: When you run `~/miniconda3/envs/foo/bin/pip list` in a terminal, does it contain `openmesh`? When you open a terminal in VS code, does the prompt show your venv prefix?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT I cannot go to Declaration, Definition or Type Definition. It always says "Declaration not found for 'om'".

Comment: @carlfriedrich it does it contain `openmesh`. In VS code, the prompt shows me the venv prefix `(foo)`, i.e. the Python Interpreter I selected.

Comment: @tlk13, were you able to figure out a solution to this? I'm facing a similar issue with AWS CDK library. I've tried re-installing VSCode with no avail.

Comment: Hi @m01010011, very cool that you found my initial issue after all this time!

Unfortunately i was not able to solve it. basically i just switched back and forth between documentation and VS Code until i had it memorised :(. if you find a solution, do let me know!

Comment: This may be the same problem I reported to Microsoft some time ago -- no intellisense for binary Python modules.  If so, they acknowledged the problem but did not want to prioritise it. This is a shame because otherwise VS Code is extremely capable across multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, auto-completion was not working with python.

The following worked for me:

Use the keyboard shortcut to open the command palette:

```
Ctrl + Shift + P
```

and search for:

```
Python: Restart Language Server
```

Hit enter. Now give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments :
*There are two types of environments that you can create for **your workspace**: virtual and conda environments.*

you have to work into a **workspace**

Answer (score 0):

Open your Terminal, activate your environment (i.e. `conda activate foo`), and then launch VS Code from within terminal in which you activated your environment (i.e. `code .` or `code /path/to/directory`). This worked for me.

If you are on Windows you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62053889/19684644)