# vscode not autocompleting python from module made with pybind11

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I have a python module named `relatpy.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` that I created using pybind11 with a custom made C++ library. When I import this module in the terminal using something like `ipython` I get functional autocompletion like the figure shows.

[image: autocompletion works in terminal]

However in vscode I don't get any autocompletion, I just get the message `Import "relatpy" could not be resolved`. The python file that imports this module can still be run just fine in vscode, just no autocompletion.

Do I have to add this module to my PYTHONPATH or how do I go about doing this? This module is also rebuilt pretty often so is there a way to get autocompletion to work even if the module changes?

I'm using pylance as the python language server in vscode.

I created the pybind11 module using the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(relatpy)

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)

file(GLOB SOURCES "../relativity/src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB HEADERS "../relativity/include/*.h")
file(GLOB BINDINGS "*.cpp")

pybind11_add_module(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${BINDINGS})

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PYTHON_DIR})
```

Comment: PyLance does not execute native code to analyze, create `.pyi` files, `ipython` uses the data avalable **after** loading/executing the `.so`, PyLance does only static analysis

Comment: How can I create `.pyi` files of a `.so` module like this? I tried using `mypy`, but that doesn't seem to work. I've never worked with it before though.

Comment: numpy has `.pyi` files, find out how they do it, AFAIK they do it by hand

Comment: If you try to add this code `"python.jediEnabled": true,` to your settings.json, does it work

Comment: No that doesn't work, but it gets greyed out in the `settings.json` even if I change to the `python.languageServer` to `Jedi`.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761750/python-autocomplete-in-vs-code-not-working-with-external-libraries-in-conda-envi#comment136552506_70761750

Answer (score 1):

Per [this comment](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/2350#issuecomment-1126109940) on the pybind issue [creating stub pyi files automatically from pybind projects](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/2350), you can use [stubgen](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubgen.html#automatic-stub-generation-stubgen), from [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/), to generate [stub files](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#stub-files), that Pylance can read.

```
pip install mypy
```

then

```
PYTHONPATH=<path to your python module> stubgen -m <your python module name>
```

(in your case, the path should be to the directory containing `relatpy.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, and your python module name is `relatpy`)

Stubgen tells you where it's put the .pyi file, in my case `out/<python module name>.pyi`. You need to move the .pyi file to sit beside your Python module, i.e. next to `relatpy.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

When I looked at the .pyi files produced, it had an `import flags` line, which VS Code had underlined. So I also did:

```
pip install flags
```

(Sometime ago, I had tried the other solution mentioned in the pybind issue, pybind11-stubgen, but could not get it to work, whereas stubgen worked without errors.)

*Edit*: the CMake code required is pretty trivial: after building your module, simply figure out the location of `stubgen` (in my case, in my virtual environment as I'd pip installed it via a requirements.txt file), and run it using a custom command.

```
pybind11_add_module(${PYMODULE_NAME} ...)
target_link_libraries(${PYMODULE_NAME} PRIVATE ... pybind11::pybind11)

# Use stubgen to create .pyi files to sit alongside the just-built python module
set(Stubgen_Executable "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/venv/bin/stubgen")
if(WIN32)
    set(Stubgen_Executable "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/venv/Scripts/stubgen.exe")
endif()
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PYMODULE_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${Stubgen_Executable} -m ${PYMODULE_NAME} -o .
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "Use stubgen to create .pyi for statement completion"
```